# How to create and use PyTorch learnable scalar variables outside of nn.Module?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am working on a multi-objective problem where I have multiple losses that I need to compute, and the total loss is just the sum of the losses. I want to have PyTorch learnable floating-point parameters `alpha`, and `beta` that act as coefficients to the individual losses. Note that the summation of losses occurs outside my NN model in the training loop:

```py
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5, eps=1e-8)

for batch in dl:

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    result = model(batch)

    loss1 = loss_fn_1(result)
    loss2 = loss_fn_2(result)
    loss3 = loss_fn_3(result)

    loss = alpha*loss1 + beta*loss2 + (1-beta)*loss3 # How to optimize alpha, beta?
                        
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

How would I declare and use the learnable parameters `alpha` and `beta`?

Comment: be aware that with this loss formula, the backpropagation will make `alpha` converge toward 0, which is probably not what you want. You probably need to add a regularization loss on your `alpha` and `beta`

Comment: @trialNerror: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Well if I understand your question correctly (and I believe it is a sensible one), you want to optimize `alpha` and `beta` with respect to a given criterion. Pytorch's implementation of backpropagation will always go toward **minimizing** the criterion. In your formula, the most obvious way to reduce the loss is to set `alpha` to zero, and that's what pytorch is gonna do. But that is probably not what you want. You probably want to optimize `alpha` and `beta` with respect to another loss function. Does that make more sense ?

Comment: @trialNerror: Thank you. I understand that `alpha` will go to 0.0 for minimization. What I don't understand is how to use regularization to fix the problem. Usually regularization is used to address overfitting to prevent parameters from going too *big*. How could it be used here?

Answer (score 2):

You can put them into a list and add them to an optimizer, for example,

```py
optimizer_for_my_params = torch.Adam([alpha, beta], lr=1e-3)
```

or separately,

```py
optimizer_alpha = torch.Adam([alpha], lr=1e-3)
optimizer_beta = torch.Adam([beta], lr=1e-3)
```

and at each step, call `zero_grad` and `step` on all optimizers.

Or you can put them in an `nn.Module` and declare them as parameters:

```py
class MyParams(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyParams, self).__init__()

    self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.))
    self.beta = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.))

  def forward(self, loss1, loss2, loss3):
    loss = self.alpha*loss1 + self.beta*loss2 + (1 - self.beta)*loss3
    return loss
```

When using it, defining a separate optimizer for the class object should do the job.

---

**Update:**
Here is a more comprehensive example for the first method.

```py
import torch
import torch.optim as optim

alpha = torch.tensor(0.)
alpha.requires_grad = True
optimizer_alpha = optim.Adam([alpha], lr=1e-3)

print(optimizer_alpha)
# Adam (
# Parameter Group 0
#     amsgrad: False
#     betas: (0.9, 0.999)
#     eps: 1e-08
#     lr: 0.001
#     weight_decay: 0
# )

out = alpha + 1

# test backward()
optimizer_alpha.zero_grad()
out.backward()
print(alpha.grad)
# tensor(1.)

# test step()
optimizer_alpha.step()
print(alpha)
# tensor(-0.0010, requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: For your first approach, how would I declare `alpha` and `beta`? I tried declaring them as `nn.Parameter`, but I get an error `cannot optimize non-leaf node`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Judging from your purpose, I think defining them as torch scalar tensors should be enough: `alpha = torch.tensor(0.)`. Of course you can initialize them to other values.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 See the update. It works on my computer. I forgot to mention that you need to set `requires_grad=True`. Also, I don't think you need to use `nn.Parameter` unless you put it in `nn.Module`.